# Django DB alternative to select_for_update

Tags: django, sqlite, postgresql, django-models

In my web app, different users could be simultaneously making requests that modify different fields on the same object.

Let's say our widget object has fields a and b which are both originally 0.

User 1's request triggers this line:

```
widget.a = 1
```

User 2's request triggers this line:

```
widget.b = 1
```

If user 2's request is saved to the DB last, the object would end up with `a=0` and `b=1`, whereas I want `a=1` and `b=1`.

Is there a way to avoid this? I know about select_for_update, but (1) it doesn't work on SQLite, which my platform's users use for easy local development, and (2) because it blocks until it can get a lock on the row it sounds like it would hurt performance unnecessarily, especially when one request doesn't actually end up modifying the object.

What I have in mind is that on `save()`, only the fields that have been changed since the object was queried get written to the DB, like applying a delta/diff to the object.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Seems you are looking for transactions:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question. There is a package called [Django Save the Change](https://github.com/karanlyons/django-save-the-change) that provides a model mixin that only saves changed fields.